# Chrome headless always shows its dock icon on osx

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Chrome `59.0.3071.115` and Chromium `61.0.3159.0` (snapshot build) on OSX in [headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), launching them from a terminal with these flags:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu
```

Everything works as expected, but a Chrome/Chromium dock icon is always displayed during their execution.

[image: Chromium dock icon on osx]

Is there a way to execute them in headless mode without having this icon always being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=750505

I hope the Chromium developers will fix this soon. You can star the issue in the meantime.